# Create stored procedure SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, database, t-sql, stored-procedures

I have created three tables in my database. The passenger and the flight table  already have info inserted.

```
create table IT260_AV.dbo.Passenger 
( "Passport ID" nvarchar(20) not null,
"Lastname" nvarchar(50),
"Firstname" nvarchar(50),
"Nationality" int ,
"Telephone" nvarchar(20),
"Email" nvarchar(50),
"Birthdate" datetime,
"NumberOfChildren" int,
"PassportExpDate" datetime)

alter table IT260_AV.dbo.Passenger
add constraint Passenger_PK primary key clustered ("Passport ID")

create table IT260_AV.dbo.Flight
("FlightNo" int not null,
"Air Company" nvarchar (50),
"Departure Date" datetime,
"Departure Time" time,
"MaximumCapacity" int,
"BookingCapacity" int)

alter table IT260_AV.dbo.Flight
add constraint FlightNo_PK primary key clustered ("FlightNo")

create table IT260_AV.dbo.Booking
("Booking Number" nvarchar(20) not null,
"Flight Number" int not null,
"Passenger ID" nvarchar(20),
"SeatNo" int not null IDENTITY(1, 1),
constraint FK_FlightNumber foreign key ("Flight Number") references Flight("FlightNo"), 
constraint FK_PassengerID foreign key ("Passenger ID") references Passenger("Passport ID") )

alter table IT260_AV.dbo.Booking
add constraint BookingNumber_PK primary key clustered ( "Booking Number")
```

I am trying to create a procedure that will take as an input a passenger’s passport and a flight number and it will create a new record in the Booking table.

The procedure should examine if the maximum capacity of the flight is sufficient before completing the booking. If insufficient, it should display a message. In addition, it should examine if the given passport is valid based on the expiration date.

Anyone have any idea what I should do?

I tried this but i still get an error:

```
create procedure sp_Booking_AV @PassengerPassport nvarchar(20), @Flightn0                     int
 as 
 begin
 declare @Capacity int , @SeatAv int , @ExpDate date
set @Capacity = (select MaximumCapacity from Flight where   FlightNo=@Flightn0)
set @SeatAv = (select max(SeatNo) from Booking)
set @ExpDate = (select PassportExpDate from Passenger where "Passport ID" =  @PassengerPassport)

if (@SeatAv is null) set @SeatAv = 0

if(@SeatAv <=@Capacity) 
   if (@ExpDate>=Convert(date,getdate()))
  insert into IT260_AV.dbo.Booking values (@PassengerPassport,@Flightn0)
    else print 'The passport has been expired';

        else  print 'The fly is fool'

      end
        go
```

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: i am kind of lost . I found some examples on the internet but i cannot really understand how it works.

Comment: I cannot undestand how i am going to connect the insert command with the function of examining the maximum capacity

Comment: Do it step by step.  Start by checking for seats and outputting yes or no depending on what you find.

Comment: Do you want this do be done in pure MySQL?

Comment: Yes i need to write it in script my sql